# Using systemd I want my Postgresql ExecStop command to run at shutdown

Tags: systemd, shutdown, postgresql

I have a set of scripts that run constantly while `Postgresql` is up. I modified the `ExecStop` commands in my `.service` file so that a special script to stop those scripts and wait for them to complete will run before the database is shut down. This all works.

However, yesterday IT shut down the server, and the `ExecStop` commands weren't run. I know this because of some chaotic results in the scripts, and because the special script logs its output to a file, and that file wasn't updated yesterday.

Note: I just looked at the history of the root user, and I think IT ran

```
shutdown -h now
```

Would that have bypassed the systemctl setup?

Can I put something in the `.service` file to make sure that `ExecStop` is run at system shutdown, or do I need to create a special service that's tied to shutdown?

I do not think that this is a duplicate of "How to run a script with systemd right before shutdown", because I do not want to create a special service that duplicates my existing Postgresql service.

I am very sure that my special script didn't run, because it appends to a log file when it runs, and that log file was last appended to about a week ago, when I last ran 'systemctl stop my-service-name.service' .

Here's the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL 9.3 main database server
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

User=postgres
Group=postgres

# Location of database directory
Environment=PGDATA=/db_tier1/main/

ExecStartPre=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/postgresql93-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} ; /bin/rm -f /db_tier2/PGSERVICE-PROD-ABORT
ExecStart=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_ctl start -D ${PGDATA} -s -w -t 300
ExecStop=/bin/sh /var/lib/pgsql/bin/PROD/run_db_pre_stop.sh ${PGDATA} ; /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_ctl stop -D ${PGDATA} -s -m fast
ExecReload=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_ctl reload -D ${PGDATA} -s

# Give a reasonable amount of time for the server to start up/shut down
TimeoutSec=600

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I would suggest doing this as its own service.  A system update is likely to blow away changes to postgresql's own `.system` file.

Comment: @PhilipCouling No, it shouldn't be a separate service (at least there's no reason for that.) Regarding modifying a service unit shipped by the system, systemd supports override units just for this purpose (see `systemctl edit` for some more details on that.) Oh and service units use a `.service` extension, I don't think there's such a thing as a `.system` file in systemd.

Answer (score 4):

systemd will execute the `ExecStop=` of all services it stops during shutdown, so your script probably *is* being executed.

One common issue is that your service unit (in this case `postgresql.service`) doesn't have all dependencies set correctly, in which case other shutdown procedure (such as shutting down networking or unmounting filesystems) might happen in parallel with your script.

In order to make sure these stay up long enough for the `ExecStop=` script to complete, you should list them in the `After=` dependencies of your service. (The order on shutdown is the reverse of that on startup, so your service's stop will happen *before* the stop of those dependencies.) For instance, you most likely want to have `After=network.target` if you need networking in your stop script.

If you're writing to filesystems other than the root, use [`RequiresMountsFor=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#RequiresMountsFor=) to ensure they'll be available during the procedure.

If you have journald and have persistent storage for it (I'd say that's likely), you can take a look at what it says, to see if it mentioned your `ExecStop=` script or some errors that happened while executing it.

For example, this command:

```
$ journalctl -u postgresql -b -1
```

It will list all logs for `postgresql.service` (assuming that's the exact name of your service unit) on the last boot of the machine (`-b -1` means the boot before the current one.) So it should show you startup at boot and stopping it during shutdown. Hopefully that helps you troubleshoot it.

Comment: @Adina Hopefully this will help... If you have further questions, please share more details from your system, such as the `.service` unit, perhaps parts of the `ExecStop=` script, journalctl output etc. It's hard to tell you specifically what's wrong in your case without further details... Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a persistent journal. I can change that, but obviously that won't help with this issue.

Comment: @Adina Even if you can't get the logs of that particular execution anymore, you might need to debug that service unit (perhaps on a non-production machine), so journal logs might come handy then.

Answer (score 1):

When `systemd` starts services, it will also create a dedicated *control group* (`cgroup` for short) for each service. You can run something like `ps ax -O cgroup:150 | grep system.slice` to see the cgroups assigned to each service, although the listing will be rather wide.

Note that if you stop and restart `postgresql` without using `systemctl` (say, with `pg_ctl` for example), the restarted `postgresql` process will no longer be a member of the control group `systemd` created for the service. As a result, `systemd` will think that the service is now down.

Running `ExecStop=` actions at shutdown for services that are known to be already down would be useless, so `systemd` will skip them.

If you have a Database Administrator who is unwilling to learn `systemctl` commands, a separate management tool that will stop and start `postgresql` in the traditional way as it deems necessary, or a well-learned Pavlovian reflex to do so yourself as part of some database operations, you might consider changing the `postgresql.service` unit to:

```
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
```

This will stop `systemd` from monitoring the actual state of the PostgreSQL database engine, but it will allow stopping and restarting the database engine in the traditional way at will without jeopardizing the `ExecStop=` actions at shutdown.

Comment: I always use systemctl to stop and start postgresql (well, except for a server start, which will start my service automatically.)